# Do Geometry/Geography points imply a direction?

Tags: google-bigquery, gis, postgis

Is the line `LINESTRING(1 1, 2 2)` the same as `LINESTRING(2 2, 1 1)` ? I would think the answer is not, if there is some directionality implied -- for example, a flight-route from Los Angeles to New York would be different than going from New York to Los Angeles, even though (in this example) it would go along the same path in both ways. Or does a `GEO` data type not involve anything like a direction and as long as two geography/geometries have all the same points (regardless of order) they are considered the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The equality really depends with your point of view or usage scenario.** If you think the line strings `LINESTRING(1 1, 2 2)` and `LINESTRING(2 2, 1 1)` as *pure features* then you may say that they are equal since they consist of exactly the same points. But if the *direction or network analysis* matters then they are certainly not equal as you have pointed out. Assume you store a Road table in PostGIS. You may use it *to display* the roads or may *calculate* the shortest paths in a navigation application. In the latter scenario the direction matters; even it is important for a road to be one-way or two way. The distinction is much like the difference between the [undirected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Undirected_graph) and [directed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) graphs.

Another point of view to evaluate the equality is to look at the PostGIS [docs](http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geometries.html). It describes the `LineString` as:

> A linestring is a path between locations. It takes the form of an
> ordered series of two or more points.

With that perspective, since it is an *ordered* set of points you may say `LINESTRING(1 1, 2 2)` and `LINESTRING(2 2, 1 1)` are *not* the same. They have different `ST_StartPoint()` and `ST_EndPoint()` values, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

the answer depends on one's definition of "same".

for `ST_Equals` they are same, as `ST_Equals` only cares with topological equivalence and DE-9IM model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM).

but you can still inspect their details, e.g. call `ST_StartPoint` on both objects, and that returns different values for these geometries.